# Can 出神 be split by something other than an aspect marker?

Tags: word, separable-verbs

The Pleco dictionary indicates that 出神 is a separable verb (离合词).
Yet, is it possible to separate 出 from 神 in 出神, by something else than an aspect marker (了, 过, 着)?

For instance 出几次神.

Comment: I don't think 出神 is a compound verb. For example: 他聽(verb)的很(adv)出神(adj); 他出神的(adv)想(verb)了想; 他出神(adv)出(verb)了很長的一段時間.

Comment: It can be an adverb, but it can also be a verb 史佩莱正在出神; 一直望着那张床出神; 但望着珂赛特他还会出神

Comment: 史佩莱正在**出神的**(adv)+(verb)+...; 他一直望(verb)着那张床出神(noun); 但望着珂赛特他还会出神 (I don't understand this sentence).

Comment: 埃纳博先生一动也不动，一直望着那张床出神。; 德纳第大娘向街上望了一眼，就望见珂赛特正在出神。; 他虽已沉入黑暗深处，但望着珂赛特他还会出神。

Comment: Note, 出神 can be translated as "empty/absent mind", a phenomenon that is associated with the act of thinking/staring hard, and the mind is concentrated on the object but absent from anything else. I disagree that a verb plus a noun can form another verb, but v + v = v is usually the case.

Comment: 但望着珂赛特他"还会(v)出(adv)神(noun)" = still will (v) out of (adv) mind (noun).

Comment: "I disagree that a verb plus a noun can form another verb" : 吃饭, 走路, 丢脸, 打字, etc.

Comment: 但望着珂赛特他"还会(v)出(adv)神(noun)" Here 会 is an auxiliary, which by definition accompanies a verb, thus 出神 is must be a verb (or a verb phrase) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb.

Comment: Also, 'out of' is not an adverb, it is a preposition

Comment: Will - **n.** 决心；意志；遗嘱；愿望; **aux.** 将；愿意；必须; **vt.** 决心；想要(某事发生)；**vi.** <旧>愿意.

Comment: In the dictionary, Out of = Motivated by (adv)

Comment: 出(v)+發/擊(v)=verb phrase; 圍(v)+攻/繞(v)=verb phrase; 圍(v)+城(n) - "circling the city" is not a verb phrase, the same as 出神.

Comment: A verb phrase is a phrase that can't be separated by inserting any word in between the words that form the phrase. 出神 does not meet the criteria.

Comment: It is correct that a verb phrase that's made up of two verbs can't be separated by inserting any word, e.g. 攻擊,  逃跑, but a verb phrase that's made up of a verb and a noun can. e.g. l呼氣, 吸氣 --> 呼大氣, 吸一口氣

Comment: @TangHo Can 作声 be split by something else than 了/着/过?

Comment: @starckman  The only thing I can think of is 不作一声. Meanwhile,  作出怪声 can be seen as a normal [verb + noun] phrase -- "作出" + "怪声"

Comment: @TangHo Thank you so much. I guess it is possible also to say in a rhetorical way: 一声都不作, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the verbs that are made up of two verbs are inseparable

Most of the verbs that are made up of a verb and a noun are separable

Example:

攻(v) + 擊(v) = 攻擊 (attack)

攻擊(v) is inseparable. It has to be 攻擊了几次, not 攻几次擊

圍(v) + 城(n) = 圍城 (siege)

圍城 (v) is separable. It can be 圍城三年 or 圍了三年城

逃(v) + 跑(v) = 逃跑 (flee)

逃跑 is inseparable. It has to be 逃跑不了, not 逃不了跑

逃(v) + 獄(n) = 逃獄 (escape from prison)

逃獄 is separable. It can be 逃獄七次 or 逃了七次獄

Since 出神 is made up of a verb and a noun, it is separable

It can be 出神片刻 or 出了片刻神

Comment: Is it possible to separate 出 from 神 in 出神, by something else than an aspect marker (了, 过, 着)?

Comment: 圍了三年城, 逃了七次獄, 出了片刻神 can do without 了--> 敵人三年不投降我們就圍足三年城, 逃七次獄都不成功, 出片刻神已被對手有機可乘

Comment: inseparable verbs cannot be split by 了, 过, or 着. Why exclude them in separable verbs? Most separable verbs that can be  split by 了, 过, or 着 can be split by a measure word or an adjective, e.g. 拍照-->拍过照 --> 拍裸照; 吃飯 --> 吃了飯--> 吃一頓飯

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I missed "or 出了片刻神" at the end of your answer.